# Does the portability feature of Java is proved in exception handling?

Tags: java, portability

Someone tell me the "portability" feature of Java is also proved in exception handling because in the JLS8 document ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html))

> An example of such a violation is an attempt to index outside the
>   bounds of an array. Some programming languages and their
>   implementations react to such errors by peremptorily terminating the
>   program; other programming languages allow an implementation to react
>   in an arbitrary or unpredictable way. Neither of these approaches is
>   compatible with the design goals of the Java SE platform: to provide
>   **portability** and robustness.

But, follow my knowledge about Java, I just know that the portability feature just involve the implementation of Java program (Write Once Run Anywhere)..

Please help me to clarify this issue and give me an example to demonstrate...Thank you!!

Comment: Exceptions (and handling of them) are part of the language - why wouldn't they be portable (you even linked the part of the language specification that states that they are part of the language)

Comment: Your question makes no sense at all. What does _"But, follow my knowledge about Java, I just know that the portability feature just involve the implementation of Java program (Write Once Run Anywhere)."_ even mean? Why do you think that exception handling has anything to do (or not to do) with portability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key sentence is this:

> Neither of these approaches is compatible with the design goals of the Java SE platform: to provide portability **and** robustness.

Note that I have emphasized a different word.

- Portability is enhanced by throwing exceptions rather than behaving in an unpredictable fashion.  If a program behaves unpredictably, then the chances are that it will behave differently on different platforms<sup>1</sup>.  That is non-portable *by definition*.
- Robustness is enhanced by not having a program "peremptorily terminate".  A program that terminates (e.g. crashes) is non-robust *by definition*.

Exceptions and exception handling in Java are designed to address both portability and robustness concerns, though (obviously) *specific* exceptions don't necessarily address both of them.

---

> I just know that the portability feature just involve the implementation of Java program (Write Once Run Anywhere)..

"Write Once Run Anywhere" is a marketing slogan that is demonstrably not true.

- It is not true in the sense that Java doesn't run on machines what nobody has implemented a JVM for.
- It is not true in the sense that there are platform differences (e.g. between Java running on Windows and Linux) that Java does not hide.  Any program that does not take proper account of these differences won't be portable.
- It is not true in the sense that Java has multiple versions and releases, and a Java program written for one version / release may not be compatible with another version / release.  (Generally, old apps will run on new Java, but not the other way around.)

However, you are correct in the sense that the aspiration is for Java programs to be able to run on multiple platforms and versions without recompilation.  That is one aspect of portability.

---

<sup>1 - Putting it another way, if a program's behavior is unpredictable, then we cannot predict that it will behave the same on different platforms.</sup>

Comment: Hi @StephenC, I can summarize your idea as follows:
"allowing an implementation to react in an arbitrary or unpredictable way" means the program does not anything when an exception occurs, so that, in this case, the "not good thing" can occurs unpredictably (we can predict what will happens)...It's right...Moreover, since unpredictable way, so the program can behave different for each platform ==> the portability is violated...It's true???

Comment: Not exactly.  The unpredictability is that we don't know *if* it will happen, *when* it will happens, or *what* its effects will be.  For example a C program writing past the end of an array could lead to the program segfaulting immediately, or a few seconds later, or it could cause the program to produce an incorrect result.  And the effects are liable to be different on different platforms ... in unpredictable ways.

Answer (score 0):

Unpredictable behaviour in other languages versus better quality with fail-fast (runtime exceptions). Yes that influences portability, and especially handling error reports. Logs play a large role in for instance the embedded market.